# SSRS:How to create report LIKe pivot table in ssrs 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I need to create  reoprt in ssrs like the pivot table in MS Excel.[image]

Above the screen shot of my requirement,I am very much confused this time .
Please provide some guidlines ,resources and links where i find the needfull help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SSRS equivalent of an Excel Pivot table is called a Matrix - in SSRS 2008, both conventional table reports and matrixes are essentially the same thing (as described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867242/what-is-the-difference-between-matrix-and-a-tablix)).

You can find out more about using matrixes in reports on Microsoft's site, such as [this article describing Table, Matrix and List objects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220592.aspx), or [this article that describes how to add a matrix to a report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Alternatively, there are plenty of other resources on the web - [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/advanced-matrix-reporting-techniques/) are a [couple](http://balavardhanreddy.over-blog.com/article-advanced-matrix-control-in-ssrs-43729818.html) of the links returned by googling "matrix ssrs".

Comment: I am able to create the report layout and also drill down features.But here is a problem I am facing ,when I export the report to excel the show and hide of drill down is not working ...<br>What should I have to do???